# How to Create web Template for Variation based(multilingual) site

Tags: site-template, variations

We have a requirement of creating about 30-35 Departmental Sub-Sites. I have variations enabled on root site. I need the publishing feature to be enabled in the sub-site as well as variations on the sub-site as well.  What is the best approach for this. I would need a lot of customization to the template like lots of custom list, libraries,site columns, content types, custom master an d page layouts, custom web parts added to the home page.

Please see below for hierarchy:

http://rootsite
http://rootsite/en-us, http://rootsite/fr-ca
http://rootsite/en-us/DepartmentSite1/en-us, http://rootsite/fr-ca/DepartmentSite1/fr-ca
http://rootsite/en-us/DepartmentSite2, http://rootsite/fr-ca/DepartmentSite2

So DepartmentSite1, DepartmentSite2 would be based of the web template, but it should provision both English as well as French variations site with all custom elements populated in both.

Answer (score 1):

What is the logic behind the last sites called /en-us /fr-ca? The url gets really hard to understand. Is it because you have an requirement to have translations even despite you are IN an variation target?

You can only have one variation root per site collection.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. I removed the en-us and fr-ca for the sub sites. But what would be the approach for creating web template for multi-lingual(variation) support.

Comment: A custom webpart probably have to handle all the resource files for each language. Use the SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(...) function.